# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 31489 Tess-two

Tags: android, tess-two

I have this error with this code

```
  public MyTessOCR(Context context)
  {
    this.context = context ;

    //initialize Tesseract API
    String language = "eng";
    datapath = this.context.getFilesDir()+ "/tesseract/";
    mTess = new TessBaseAPI();

    checkFile(new File(datapath + "tessdata/"));
    mTess.setDebug(true);

    mTess.init(datapath, language); // it crashes here 

    Log.d("OK","OK");

}
```

I have tried to change the eng.traineddata but still ??

The weird thing is that when I create a new project and I run exactly the same code, it works. The project where it doesn't work is a bit old (2 years old).
Maybe there is an update to do ?

and it fails exactly here :

```
       boolean success = nativeInitOem(datapath, language, ocrEngineMode); //ocrEngineMode = 3
```

Comment: Related? https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/issues/197

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally the problem was with eng.traineddata. 
I was still using the old one why my function doesn't copy it if there is one in the folder. And the old one was still in the folder.

Comment: So should we change the `checkFile` method to overwrite the traindata files?